# How to change the direction of a popup menu Item from right to left?

Tags: android, popupmenu

I know this question was asked many times and I used many solutions but it doesn't work for me . I want to change the direction of my `Menu` to `rtl` using a `Popup` but It doesn't work .

my `menu`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layoutDirection="rtl">
<item
    android:id="@+id/more"
    android:title="@string/menue" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/rate"
    android:title="@string/rate"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:title="@string/share" />
```

my `popup`

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, imageButton );
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.app_menue, popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.more:
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse(res.getString(R.string.moreApps)));
                            startActivity(intent);
                            break;
                        case R.id.rate:
                            Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent1.setData(Uri.parse(res.getString(R.string.rateApp)));
                            startActivity(intent1);
                            break;
                        case R.id.share:
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            myIntent.setType("text/plain");
                            String shareBody = "Share our app";
                            myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareBody);
                            myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, res.getString(R.string.shareApp));
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share using"));
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            popup.show();
        }
    });
```

And in my `Manifest`

```
    android:supportsRtl="true"
```

Comment: Can you specify which approaches you have tried, so we don't recommend things that already didn't work for you?

Comment: @pushasha Please can you tell me what do you mean of approach ?

Comment: You mentioned in your question "I used many solutions but it doesn't work for me". I'm asking which "solutions" you are referring to. Also, can you show us what makes you think the menu is not in RTL? Is the text not aligned correctly?

Comment: I used the solution which I mentioned it in my question . Then I tried to use `Gravity.RIGHT ` like this `PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, imageButton , Gravity.RIGHT);` But in this line I have to put the min SDK to 19 and I don't want to do that . And doesn't work too

Comment: Yes it is . And I tried to set the `gravity` to right but it doesn't work too .

Comment: I just tried out your code, and you're absolutely right -- the items aren't aligned properly, even if I add `layout_gravity` and `gravity` to every item. Very strange. You may need to make a custom layout and use `ListPopupWindow` (which I've never tried myself), if no one can provide another answer...

Comment: What about `Menu` xml ? will I use it in the custom layout ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a solution .

Making my own style like this

```
<style name="menuStyle">
<item name="android:layoutDirection">rtl</item>
</style>
```

Then add this code

```
Context myContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(MainActivity.this,R.style.menuStyle); 
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(myContext , myView);
```