# How to show the Radio Button icon on the left side in a Popup Menu group?

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

I have a Radio Button group in Popup Menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:id="@+id/mode_group"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/red"
            android:title="Red" />
        <item android:id="@+id/white"
            android:title="White" />
        <item android:id="@+id/blue"
            android:title="Blue" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

It shows the icon to the right of the title:

[image: popup menu screenshot]

Is it possible to configure it to show the icon on the left side?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49901594/how-to-change-the-direction-of-a-popup-menu-item-from-right-to-left)

Comment: @MohammedAlaa, thx, it does put the radio button at left, but text does not follow button immediately, so the button is left aligned and text is right aligned with big gap in between.   like [bt xxxx space xxxx Red],          Looking for some thing like [bt . Red  xxxx space xxxx  ].

Comment: is this like what you want to implement [image](https://imgur.com/r60iceP)

Comment: yes, but the `android:supportsRtl="true"` . pushes button at left and text at far right

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to achieve this

**java code**

```
 Context contextWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(MainActivity.this, R.style.PopupStyle);
 PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(contextWrapper,v);

           /*  The below code in try catch is responsible to display icons*/

           try {
               Field[] fields = popup.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
               for (Field field : fields) {
                   if ("mPopup".equals(field.getName())) {
                       field.setAccessible(true);
                       Object menuPopupHelper = field.get(popup);
                       Class<?> classPopupHelper = Class.forName(menuPopupHelper.getClass().getName());
                       Method setForceIcons = classPopupHelper.getMethod("setForceShowIcon", boolean.class);
                       setForceIcons.invoke(menuPopupHelper, true);
                       break;
                   }
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pop_up, popup.getMenu());

           popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
               public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                           "Clicked popup menu item " + item.getTitle(),
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   return true;
               }
           });

popup.show();
```

**pop_up.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/red"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/presence_online"
        android:title="Red" />
    <item android:id="@+id/white"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/presence_online"
        android:title="White" />
    <item android:id="@+id/blue"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/presence_online"
        android:title="Blue" />
</menu>
```

and if you want to change the menu style

in **styles.xml**

```
<style name="PopupStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
   <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

or if you want to create custom layout check [link1](http://www.apnatutorials.com/android/android-popup-menu.php?categoryId=2), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706495/how-to-pass-a-custom-layout-to-a-popupmenu)